# Find the growth rate for $y=4^{x +1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question on my math homework.

> What's the growth rate for $y=4^{x +1}$?

I just need to find the growth rate. I know how to do these kind of problems except for this one. This would be a big help if someone can help me on this question.

Comment: What does the term "growth rate" mean to you?

Comment: The growth rate is in a percentage

Comment: @lea Give an example of a growth rate problem solved please.

Comment: f(x)=  42509(1.23) to the x power

Comment: The growth factor is 1.23 and the growth rate is 23%

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat do you know how to solve this?

Comment: $f(x)=42509\times 1.23^x$ gives growth factor $1.23$?

Comment: You have $4\times 4^x$, does this help? Exponents work like this $a^b\times a^c =a^{b+c}$. Please take the time to understand this. It is the foundation of your misunderstanding and it will help you a heap. The base $a$ is just any number which is the same, and the exponents are added.

Comment: yes the growth rate would be 23%

Answer (score 0):

I'll make some assumptions about what you mean, which I think are right-but let me know if it looks like I've misinterpreted. One way to work out problems like this is to plug in a couple of $x$ value. So when $x=0,y=4^{0+1}=4^1=4$. And when $x=1,y=4^{1+1}=4^2=16$. We could even check a third point: when $x=2,y=4^{2+1}=4^3=64$. As $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $y$ goes from $4$ to $16=4\times 4$, and as $x$ goes from $1$ to $2$, $y$ goes from $16$ to $4\times 16$. So each time $x$ increases by $1$, $y$ is multiplied by $4$. Thus the growth rate is $300\%$, because multiplying by $4$ is adding $300\%$, that is, $4y=y+300\% y$. And the growth factor would be $4$.

A more mechanical solution is to remember that $a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$. So $4^{1+x}=4\times 4^x$, and from the example you gave it looks like you know that if $y=4\times 4^x$, the growth factor is $4$ and the growth rate is $300\%$.

Comment: Good answer(+1). Off-topic comment: Some users are pedantic about using `$\times$` in place of `*`.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to do 300%, but I wasn't sure about my answer. Thank you again!

Comment: @lea glad this helped! If you're asking questions here in the future, consider including ideas like that in the question. Even if you don't know they're right, it helps us see what you've been doing.

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge ah, I don't think I've ever typed that operation out on here. I'll change it.